# Migrate From MS SQL To Postgres With Hibernate

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, postgresql

We are having MS SQL 2008 as database with Hibernate.

Now we are planning to move on to Postgres.

I know that Postgres does not have auto increment feature for primary key column.

I heard about SERIAL data type or Sequences for each table and then using `nextval` with primary key.

MS SQL Database is large enough containing around 150 tables.

So, I want opinions and want to know that Should We go by create sequences or SERIAL will work.

Which one could be better option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked in other way. I gave `<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>` in `hibernate.cfg.xml`. SO, tables are created on first run.

Then the requirement changed and I needed to get data for only 12-15 tables. So, I generated a Script for it using MS SQL Server 2008.

Then of course manually altered sysntax for each table's insert.

There are few things which is required.

1. In MSSQL we had `tinyint` as datatype for `boolean`. So, Manually conversion into 'true' and 'false' required for Postgres.
2. MS SQL exports `timstamp` in HEXA and gives you `CAST ... AS DATETIME` during script generation. I changed them to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in Postgres.

Answer (score 2):

In PostgreSQL serial type is automatic, just like auto-increment in MSSQL/MySQL etc. Try for example:

```
create temporary table test (
  id serial primary key,
  data text
);
insert into test (data) values ('foo'), ('bar');
select * from test;
```

```
 id | data
----+------
  1 | foo
  2 | bar
(2 rows)
```